# maven dependencies source code download

Tags: maven

I have searched on stackoverflow forum for this specific question but I havenn't found any answer. Basically I download maven dependenciesnusing this command:

mvn dependency:sources -f pom.xml

the command works fine and lot of files (sources jar) are downloaded in the download folder. The dependencies reported in pom.xml are downloaded and also all the dependencies tree.

Now it's clear to me that for each dependency several files are downloaded (binary, sources, sha1 and so on). I am only interested to the sources jar file.

The problem is that someone told me that in the download folder maven in addition to all the sources for dependency download also some maven dependency. I look at the documentation but I haven't found it.

Can someone confirm if this is true? If so, I can remove them?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you pull in some dependencies would there be anything wrong with that?  By the way, most IDEs (such as IntelliJ), allow you to attach sources for Maven dependencies.  This will allow you to easily bring up source code akd even debug the dependency code.

Comment: Consider that I need to use the command in a shell script to automate some task. What I need is that in the downloaded folder only sources for my dependencies are downloaded. If maven download something else I want to discard it. So going back to my original question: does maven download extra stuff when "mvn dependency:sources -f pom.xml" command is used? If so, how I can determine which one to discard? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by

> "in addition to all the sources for dependency download also some maven
>   dependency"

By default, Maven will resolve the artifact in addition to the sources you want. This means checksums, POM, main artifact, etc.

If I am understanding you correctly, I believe this will do the trick for you:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -Dclassifier=sources
```

This will put the sources of your dependencies *only* in `target/dependency`.